# Append selected value in the middle of a URL

Tags: php

Any idea how I would append the URL to the place where it says VALUEHERE? I am not sure how or if it is even possible:

```
<form method="get" action="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/discover/?search_query=&orderby=blank&tax_category=VALUEHERE&wpas=1">
    <fieldset>
        <select name="">
            <option value="">all categories</option>
            <option value="college-students">college-students</option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? ಠ_ಠ

Comment: Did you even read my question?

Comment: You need `JavaScript`, insert the selected category `onchange` event of select.

Comment: Your question is unclear - what value are you trying to insert there? Is it the form selection or something else?

Comment: It is the selected value in the form :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery :

```
var url = $("form").attr("action"); // get the URL;
url = url.replace("VALUEHERE", $("form select").val());
alert(url); // your final url
```

Comment: Hi thanks...now I have this, but it does not seem to work:       http://hastebin.com/mipuwusepi.js

Comment: Ok, but when I add `window.location.href = url;` I can't even select it before it reloads...see: http://jsfiddle.net/qKT2m/1/

Comment: Ok, I see what you did...thank yo so much :) I learned a lot :D